# not able to load localhost:3000/api/auth/register (404 Not Found)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to nodejs and i am not able to figure out why i am getting (Cannot GET /api/auth/register) when i am trying to load (http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register)

auth.js file

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/User');

//Register
router.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    const newUser = new User(
        {
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
        }
    );
    try {
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const userRoute = require('./routes/users');
const authRoute= require('./routes/auth');

const app = express();

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{useNewUrlParser:true},()=>{
    console.log("Connected to DB");
});

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan('common'));

app.use('/api/users',userRoute);
app.use('/api/auth',authRoute);

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("backend running");
});
```

[File Structure Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh1rG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot GET /api/auth/register

means you are sending a get request to a post route.
you have defined your register route as **post**

```
router.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
```

there is no **get** route
that is why you are getting the error change the request method to post where ever you are sending the request from. I am assuming it's postman.

Answer (score 0):

If using NextAuth.js ; This error happens when **[...nextauth].js** file is not found inside **pages**/**api**/**auth**.

Make sure the file is there and the filename is written correctly.

Reference: https://next-auth.js.org/errors#configuration